# Why does enclosing a single char in brackets in a regex exclude the grep itself when grepping ps?

Tags: regex, grep

If I perform the following grep on my Linux box:

```
$ ps -ef | grep bash
root      2286     1  0 Jun06 ?        00:03:15 /bin/bash /etc/init.d/zxy100wd
wmiller   6436  6429  0 Jun06 pts/0    00:00:01 bash
wmiller  10707  6429  0 Jun07 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
wmiller  10795  6429  0 Jun07 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
wmiller  16220  6436  0 06:55 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto bash
```

Note the last line is reporting the grep itself because the word "bash" is in the args to grep.

But, if instead I put [] around any letter in "bash" I get:

```
$ ps -ef | grep ba[s]h
root      2286     1  0 Jun06 ?        00:03:15 /bin/bash /etc/init.d/zxy100wd
wmiller   6436  6429  0 Jun06 pts/0    00:00:01 bash
wmiller  10707  6429  0 Jun07 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
wmiller  10795  6429  0 Jun07 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
```

No info on the grep this time!

So, why does enclosing a letter in the search term, i.e. the regex, in brackets keep grep from reporting itself here?  I though [s] meant "any character from the [] enclosed set consisting of the character "s".

Comment: You should quote the `ba[s]h` argument. If there happens to be a file in your current directory named `bash`, the pattern `ba[s]h` will be expanded by the shell to `bash`, the name of the file. (The string `ba[s]h` is being treated by the shell as a filename matching pattern, and by `grep` as a regular expression; they're subtly different.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the expression `ba[s]h` (or `[b]ash`, or...) just matches `bash`, not `ba[s]h` (or `[b]ash`, or...).

So the `grep` command is looking for all lines with `bash`:

```
root      2286     1  0 Jun06 ?        00:03:15 /bin/bash /etc/init.d/zxy100wd
wmiller   6436  6429  0 Jun06 pts/0    00:00:01 bash
wmiller  10707  6429  0 Jun07 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
wmiller  10795  6429  0 Jun07 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
```

but

```
wmiller  16220  6436  0 06:55 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ba[s]h
```

does not match because it is not exactly `bash`.

Comment: Oh duh.  Headslaps willingly accepted.  It's so obvious once you know the answer.  Well done.

Comment: No need to headslaps, I was also very surprised about this behaviour the first time I saw it!

Comment: Yep.  Got buried last week.

Comment: I just discovered this... oh man. Yeah, everyone asking this question is trying to look at the *regular expression* for answers, not the commandline...

Answer (score 1):

[Fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17109265/970195) nails it with the explanation of the character class trick. I just wanted to point out the other method I used quite often albeit a bit longer than what you already know was to use `-v` option of `grep` command.

```
ps -ef | grep bash | grep -v grep
```

Comment: As ight be my usual method, either solution would make a great candidate for a script.  Something named gps just to confuse everyone!  :-)