# BASH: How to avoid displaying the last line in grep?

Tags: bash, grep, ps

I'm parsing some information from ps -ef |grep process but it always displays in the output of grep the last line which is the grep itself.
How can I get the output of grep without the last line?
The output looks like that:

```
root@itaig-lt:~# ps -ef |grep gnome-terminal
itaig     3307  2306  0 09:37 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c gnome-terminal
itaig     3308  3307  0 09:37 ?        00:01:58 gnome-terminal
root      7055  5047  0 13:37 pts/10   00:00:00 grep --color=auto gnome-terminal
root@itaig-lt:~#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things:

Grep exluding the `grep` itself:

```
ps -ef |grep gnome-terminal | grep -v grep
```

or add a string condition that is not matched by this `grep` ([see explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17109265/1983854)):

```
ps -ef |grep [g]nome-terminal
```

Comment: Why didn't i think about it? grep -v grep would be suffice! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try searching for something which won't match the `grep` command line:

```
ps -ef | grep [g]nome-terminal
```