# Inconsistency between perl grep and cli grep

Tags: linux, perl, grep

I am doing the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;  
use warnings;  

my $proc = `ps -ef|grep -c myscriptname`;  
print $proc;
```

This prints 2 when I run it inside the script.

`ps -ef|grep -c myscriptname` on the command line just shows:  1
Why?

same for `my $proc = qx/ps -ef|grep -c myscriptname/`

**UPDATE**
To be clear I run this snippet from `somerandomscript.pl`

**Update 2**
Following the advice of edorqui I remove `-c` getting:

```
12013 15777 15776 0 14:11 pts/6 00:00:00 sh -c ps -ef | grep myscriptname   
12013 15779 15777 0 14:11 pts/6 00:00:00 grep myscriptname Argument "12013 15777 15776 0 14:11 pts/6 00:00:00 sh -c ps..." isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at somerandomscript.pl line 8
```

from inside the script

Comment: Did you display the hits? Would one of them be the grep itself?

Comment: This is a rather bad way to determine that you have a process running particularly when it's possible to have more than one instance of the process (or script) running.

Comment: @devnull:What is the best way?

Comment: One way is to make the script write the PID to a file and remove it when the script ends (maybe at the end of the script itself).  Now whenever you need to check whether the script is running, poll for the file instead.

Answer (score 5):

The `ps -ef` command is showing the grep itself.

To skip this behaviour, try grepping for a regex condition that does not match the grep itself:

```
ps -ef | grep myscript[n]ame
```

or whatever similar can make it:

```
ps -ef | grep myscriptnam[e]
```

#### Explanation

If you run a `sleep` command in the background:

```
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 9768
```

and then look for it with `ps -ef`:

```
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
me    9768  3673  0 14:00 pts/6    00:00:00 sleep 100
me    9771  3673  0 14:00 pts/6    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sleep
```

You get two lines: the process itself and the `grep` command looking for it. To avoid it and show just the process itselves, we can either:

```
$ ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep sleep
```

or use a regex in the code so that the grep process is not matched:

```
$ ps -ef | grep slee[p]
me    9768  3673  0 14:00 pts/6    00:00:00 sleep 100
```

because line

```
me    9771  3673  0 14:00 pts/6    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sleep
```

does not match in `grep slee[p]`.

[See explanation in a related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17109265/1983854).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `myscript[n]ame`. Also I check from another script.Please see update in OP

Comment: But I am running the script from **another** script. It is not that I get 2 because my script + grep. I test for *another* script name.

Comment: What if you just `grep myscriptname` (without -c) and print the results? Which one is missing?

Comment: When I run that I get from the script: `12013    15777 15776  0 14:11 pts/6    00:00:00 sh -c ps -ef | grep myscriptname  
12013    15779 15777  0 14:11 pts/6    00:00:00 grep myscriptname  
Argument "12013    15777 15776  0 14:11 pts/6    00:00:00 sh -c ps..." isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at somerandomscript.pl line 8.`

Comment: From cli I get: `12013    16965 15732  0 14:13 pts/6    00:00:00 grep myscriptname`

Comment: @Cratylus Mmmm feel free to update my answer with this output so I can see it properly. Comments are really bad to check code lines!

Comment: Updated OP for your convenience

Comment: @Cratylus now I see. The 2nd line shows that there is a problem when calling the `grep -c` command.

Comment: @fedorqui, no, the 2nd line is an artifact of the perl script Cratylus is actually using, intermingling perl's STDERR warning with output.  When Cratylus removed the `-c` from his grep invocation, he changed the content of `$proc`.  What he didn't show us is that he's doing something like `if ($proc > 0) ...` in the script, and perl is now complaining that `$proc` isn't numeric.

Comment: @fedorqui, which is another way of saying, your original interpretation is quite right.  :)  From the CLI, Cratylus' `ps` typically completes before the `grep` even enters the process table.

Comment: @pilcrow you are very good tracing the errors :) well done, now it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Cratylus can you check the comments by pilcrow he just wrote? Interesting to trace what was happening before and what happens now when using `grep` without `-c`.

Comment: @pilcrow:Yes you are correct! I was checking for `if($proc > 0)`.

Comment: @fedorqui:See my comment to pilcrow

Answer (score 1):

I suposse your perl script is named "myscriptname".

When you run this script, you have a new process (perl myscriptname.pl), and it's showed by the ps -ef command. The other one is related to the grep command (it has the text you are looking for)

Answer (score 1):

[@fedorqui's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18146160/132382) is right on -- the `grep` is matching its own invocation in the process table, and perhaps that of its parent shell, too, though timing issues mean this does not always happen from the CLI.

However, another approach, avoiding `grep` in favor of perl, would be:

```
my $count = () = qx(ps -e -o cmd) =~ /myscriptname/mg;
# Now $count tells you the number of times myscriptname appears in the process table
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9538604/132382) for why the empty parens are used above.  Note, too, that you don't need the *full* `ps` output (`-f`), you just want to match on the command name (`-o cmd`).

Comment: +1. But I don't fully agree with your explanation. I think now that the count is 2 because it counts the `grep` itself **and** the spawned shell having `grep` as its argument

Comment: @Cratylus, yes, good clarification; I'll update to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [pgrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) and the [pkill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) commands. These are standard Linux commands are are way easier to use than trying to do a `ps` and then a grep.

Also, if you do use `ps`, take a look at the `-o` options. These let you display the columns you want, and give you a way to strip out the heading.